# Is there an "efficient" algorithm to compute hyperexponentation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity, hyperoperation, ackermann-function

Preface: understand that this should all be modulo some fixed $m$; otherwise the numbers become so ridiculously large that the question makes no sense. That said, I'll leave $m$ off the notation to make it more clear.

---

Hyperexponentation can be [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation#Definition) recursively as follows:

$a\uparrow_n 0=1$

$a\uparrow_0 b=ab$

$a\uparrow_{n+1}b+1 = a\uparrow_n(a\uparrow_{n+1}b)$

For small $n$ you recover familiar operations: $a\uparrow_1 b=a^b$, and $a\uparrow_2 b = a^{a^{a^{\cdots a}}}$ (repeated $b$ times).

Computation is challenging. Since $a\uparrow_{n+1}b$ tends to be "quite large," computing $a\uparrow_{n+1}b+1$ is only plausible if there is an "efficient algorithm" for $\uparrow_n$.

There is such an algorithm for $a\uparrow_1b$ (exponentiation), which runs essentially in logarithmic time in $b$, which follows essentially from the fact that $a\uparrow_1 2b=(a\uparrow_1b)\uparrow_1 2$.

However, I don't see an obvious equivalent, even for $\uparrow_2$ -- while the iterative nature seems like it should work out, it doesn't seem true that $a\uparrow_2 (2b) = (a\uparrow_2 (b)) \uparrow_2 2$, or any variation of the right I can think of.

Is there a way to compute this more efficiently?

Note there may be a connection to the Ackermann function, where (at least according to Wikipedia), $A(m, n)=2\uparrow_{m-2}(n+3) - 3$.

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829351/efficient-algorithm-for-calculating-the-tetration-of-two-numbers-mod-n) a similar (unanswered) question regarding specifically tetration.

Comment: @Mark That's unfortunate ...

Answer (score 1):

### For modular arithmetic:

---

A modification of Euler's totient theorem can be given as

> When $b>\log_2(p)$ we have
>
> $$a^b\equiv a^{(b\bmod c)+c}\pmod p\tag{$\star$}$$
>
> where $c=\varphi(p/\gcd(a^{\lfloor\log_2(p)\rfloor},p))$ and $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

which allows us to repeatedly push $\bmod$ into the exponent. This terminates when we reach either $p=1,\gcd(a^p,p)=p,$ or we've reached the end the power tower (or something we can directly compute).

After that, we can work our way down with modular exponentiation by squaring, as you have noted.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVbbjts2EH3XV0xibGpvbK9IWb4E9eYhyGNQoO2b4SwoiZYJy5SqC7JBkW/fzlB3e72bAm4JwZbI4cyZMxcyLbzvT4P1y2NgDeAPKSHfS9jFcS5TyKSfq1jjZwo4SKLIRCgB5/z4mBS50iGIr189OMYB@CTxmpWnJFVHmcEaNnwMztayQj@A9eQexBg8@NuCwQV4MIBPxijuxj1Dkh8RKiBYhISgfy78SAVS6HJBRGGcqnx/hHYMXrAB@Bgga/DGIG48@LZXkcSJN2uwcTGVeZFqENYPy0Knk/hbA36MDFzC34cvOow16GMdfe9hRFuJFLkMIPurECnJXMReQU8Nswzfatj3BnW9MqS/WxAjuEHjagfeNA6Cj0ZC0LpoVs2cB3dr4PgqddA6j0rIfZU9mGDivqOKIpk@pMJT2vChL0eyR8mfMsszk2CkSkQqP@GgjewXY2Pyu7GBLOaXA3nGioGdp4UknxFh6RQ@mHqgJ0QYYcgAVdvTaVA6n0pxoA1BS1LQJwQfT2SKqNXwK3B7tqjAf8T83lq1Kx/MMnMWztx16mWT/n2Jlb202YpVEg4bw@JMhrsOn9s2a7WMwT0VcjhzbYctXNYRQm1duc70GBjaYvjF6H01Bo7vHP8Jg2O2VRwJ4sg4bVQ9UvRNHWywBoIx6NKEF8cRJdQjFQ4bmbkDrKtsLLPzgEAzePfOCFfAGtIfKUplaGo7qOwWHik7dTV7gPdlutcBaYK9E1Fmon0gPdlpClMuUA4ne/VT@Wpy8XOBCfhLBnmcK6lz2BW6bJCD1/a2talbJsviQTbLltiUKWZYtYS5elOVWM2cbpdLEk8kmrxEv8BtGoE2YSCu39Rlu6kiZayo1gJUeKZJke2HalRNErLJmv7uVDVlsKgGR0dHHQxF8eH/j5lZ1/uOGl3W/L3Jk34Hw8TNZZ4KE8SfaeNnfbzXyF@KPmLwCXiZrLg9G75dvzbejlrpUTe7k6FN3zLKUK@4pl5Tqg2NvsAi8qqSlboN3b@y07N0aqvSzK6qWdAJ1tHOr6odmx0GnfodPv52BCYI2N/t1qLzX1m8ve0bnbU2Z1e1OXddZ254hDrJegdfMjQMJ8MQOw1eyDbtMfBF5PtpFIccRaZ5/KAIsUFtNiS0Azvvxoc7CKtJ/y4JSXZnPmtEZeWEZNy/auVUh0FWRHnvBOu2BPr2JngAJuEW3uMvudBF1@gsFY2sH0@DS3frqmmcXJcnzwyS/q3IycqH3rX1orQPZ4Om6Wb9zDSdeefTl3Sn8iiUDmTak37eS4vukEu2tLkz5zZnfLV0F8v5zGYW3ahnM75cOsxx3cXctWd0jXEdy6cbK3OXnNlLzud8wVZL5sxnbNFv0JuqOW@f/gE)

Example:

$818023620212985786400\uparrow\uparrow442883135576504326053\pmod{1158210822627198136417}$

$$a=818023620212985786400\\\begin{array}{c|c|c}p&\gcd(a^{\lfloor\log_2(p)\rfloor},p)&\varphi(p/\gcd)\\\hline1158210822627198136417&1&1158210822627198136416\\1158210822627198136416&32&24118439168417024424\\24118439168417024424&8&1676147829304314240\\1676147829304314240&640&1472026782156480\\1472026782156480&320&2787929510040\\2787929510040&40&46196895888\\46196895888&16&1437004800\\1437004800&25600&29160\\29160&40&486\\486&2&162\\162&2&54\\54&2&18\\18&2&6\\6&2&2\end{array}$$

Since $\gcd(a^1,2)=2$, we stop here. Now working back:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}p&(b\bmod c)+c&a^{(b\bmod c)+c}\bmod p\\\hline2&-&0\\6&2&1\\18&7&10\\54&28&10\\162&64&10\\486&172&172\\29160&658&18640\\1437004800&47800&260300800\\46196895888&1697305600&32572251856\\2787929510040&78769147744&910022074840\\1472026782156480&3697951584880&903930403260160\\1676147829304314240&2375957185416640&1215567107351528320\\24118439168417024424&2891714936655842560&14632068328029956416\\1158210822627198136416&38750507496446980840&373675920273457955680\\1158210822627198136417&1531886742900656092096&105094019098433015730\end{array}$$

Hence the remainder is $105094019098433015730$.

In the case of tetration, this directly gives us a method to compute it's last digits. In the case of higher hyperoperators, we can use the same strategy, working out a lower bound of the tetration height and then checking if the remainder is uniquely determined.

---

$(\star)$ This follows from a combination of the Chinese remainder theorem and Euler's totient theorem. $a^p$ is computed using modular exponentiation by repeated squaring as you have noted. The $\gcd$ is computed with the Euclidean algorithm. $\varphi$ is computed by iteratively searching for prime factors and be sped up using faster factorization algorithms.

---

### For non-modular arithmetic:

---

There is no such algorithm possible since there are no nice relationships for $a\uparrow^nb$ for any $n\ge2$.

That problem aside, this isn't even reasonable to consider for any $a,b\ge2$ because the results quickly grow to a size that will make arithmetic on them slow, unless one chooses to go for a rough approximation.

This latter issue, however, can be circumvented if $0<a<e^{1/e}$ for tetration, where it converges. When $a>e^{-e}$ is in this range, then we may approximate it with

$$a\uparrow^2b\simeq q+[(a\uparrow^2n)-q]\ln(q)^{b-n}$$

for large $b$ and $q=a^q$. As $n\to\infty$ this approximation improves but relies on a large amount of precision. This can be avoided by using Aitken's delta squared acceleration method to make it converge faster. When $a<e^{-e}$, the same approach can be taken, but by considering solutions to $q=a^{a^q}$.

Of course, the same approach cannot be used for higher hyperoperations, since they require continuous lower hyperoperations and there is no agreed upon extension of tetration to non-integer heights.

Comment: See note at the top of the question; this was pertaining to going modulo a fixed m. Otherwise of course it grows so quickly the notion of efficiency is laughable, as you say.

Comment: Ah okay @RichardRast